Issues finding a formula that have 3 cells involved
Need a formula that automatically puts an expiration date 1 year or 6 months after a date entered in a previous cell.
Example:
IF cell A>=90, then Cell C is 1 year after Cell B date
&
IF cell A<=89.9, then Cell C is 6 months after Cell B date
Please Help! Thank you

You can use the following formula:
=EDATE(B1,IF(A1>=90,12,6))

Remember to format the resulting cell as date.


Using only EDATE()


=EDATE(B1,12/((A1<90)+1))


Using EOMONTH()


=EOMONTH(B1,12/((A1<90)+1)-1)+DAY(B1)


NOTE: If the output cells are not formatted as Dates then format the cells as Dates as in Excel they are stored as number. Select the output range hit CTRL+1 --> Format Cells --> Number Tab --> Category --> Date --> Ok. 

